# Create Service broker for Play Framework Api

Tags: scala, playframework, cloud-foundry

I have created a sample play framework api which has one endpoint.

`http://play-demo-broker.cfapps.io/say?number=20` 
Which just return me number that have passed.

I am able successfully deploy the service. Next want this service to Act like `service broker`
For same want to register this as by using below command

```
 cf create-service-broker play-demo-broker admin admin http://play-demo-broker.cfapps.io --space-scoped
```

This command it giving me below error -

```
The service broker rejected the request. Status Code: 404 Not Found
```

Not sure what is causing this issue as there not much information available for Play Framework Service broker Setup.

Comment: If you want to have it function as a proper service then you need to implement the Open Service Broker API spec. You might not need to totally implement every aspect of the spec, but you'll definitely need to implement the catalog API. https://github.com/openservicebrokerapi/servicebroker/blob/master/spec.md#catalog-management, When you create your service broker, Cloud Controller is going to request the catalog from your service. That allows Cloud Controller to know what services are available for users. Beyond that, you'll need to implement provisioning and binding. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The play framework is implemented above the akka packages. Akka rejects paths that are not implemented.

If I an not mistaken, `cf create-service-broker` command access the / endpoint. If you implemented only `say?number=20` endpoint, then be default all other paths, such as the empty path, are rejected by Akka.

In order to open that endpoint you need to add it into the routes.
For example you can add:

```
GET     /            controllers.ControllerName.GetEmptyPath
```

And implement the `GetEmptyPath` method in `ControllerName`

Comment: This already there in the code `GET     /                           controllers.HomeController.index
`